# CS cockpit perspective is not coming in Hybris-1811

Tags: e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I have added CS-Agent role for my use. After login into backoffice, I can see below perspectives in the dropdown, but not cs perspective. Did I miss anything?

- Administration
- Product Cockpit
- Adaptive Search
- Check Warehousing Availability

Comment: do you have the CS cockpit specific extensions added into your localextensions.xml file ?

Answer (score 1):

Need to add below user groups:

- customersupportagentgroup
- customersupportdirectorrole
- customersupportmanagergroup
- customersupportsupervisorrole